# Add a folder in a sequence of folders and rename the other folders

Tags: directory, rename, mkdir

I have x number of folders

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
......
folder100
```

What I want to do is;

```
add folder2
reorder
```

So now:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
......
folder101
```

So now, the folder that was folder2 is folder3, and etc.

Example:
folder2 -> folder3, folder3 -> folder4, folder4 -> folder5

The folder1 remain intact.

To be more precise I want to automate this

```
$ mkdir 1 2 3 4 5
$ ls
1 2 3 4 5
$ mkdir 2_1
$ ls
1 2 2_1 3 4 5
$ mv 5 6
$ ls
1 2 2_1 3 4 6
$ mv 4 5
$ mv 3 4
$ mv 2 3
$ mv 2_1 2
$ ls
1 2 3 4 5 6
$
```

How do I do this in bash?

Comment: you already had a "folder3"; did you mean that you wanted to create a new "folder2" and rename the old folder2 (and upwards) to accomodate the new one?

Comment: Ok, now is more comprehensive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in {100..2} ; do mv $f $((f+1)); done
x="?_1"
y=$(echo $x | cut -b 1-1)
mv $x $y
```

It's very manual, but solves faster the initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for..` clause with a brace expression for enumeration plus inline arithmetic; something like this:

```
for f in {100..2} ; do mv $f $((f+1)) ; done
```

That would take care of moving "up" all folders from 100 down to 2 one step.

More generically, you could use a script that discovers the insert point X from the folder name pattern X_1, and the highest number folder name before "making the hole". Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
X=*_1
F=( $(ls * | sort -nr) )
for f in {$F..${X%_1}} ; do mv $f $((f+1)) ; done
mv $X ${X%_1}
```

Note that `$F` is an array of all folder names, numerically sorted from highest to lowest number, so `$F` by itself is the highest number. Also, the format `${X%_1}` means "`$X` with the ending `_1` removed". The format `$((f+1))` means "the value of `f` plus 1".

The script doesn't handle "insert" past the highest number.

Comment: I still do not see how can be this done.

Comment: Did you try the suggested command or the script?

Comment: Should be better be used a while? the set of items is not fixed to 100.

Comment: It gives me 
loop.sh: 3: loop.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: The variable X=*_1 saves every element, when the _1 is removed, selects all the elements, so can not be used ${X%_1}

Comment: for f in {100..2} ; do mv $f $((f+1)) ; done works perfectly

Comment: there is a lot of errors for adding multiple solutions after "in" with variables, the good and faster "generical" solution I will publish it.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv 'folder(<2->)(#q/nOn)' 'folder$(($1 + 1))' &&
  mkdir folder2
```

Or for your automatic renaming based on the presence of `folder<n>_1` folders:

```
setopt extendedglob
for dir ([-._[:alpha:]]##<->_1(N/nOn)) {
  [[ $dir = (#b)(*)(<->)_1 ]]
  zmv "($match[1])(<$match[2]->)(#q/nOn)" '$1$(($2 + 1))' &&
    mv "$dir" "${dir%_1}" || break
}
```

Example:

before:

```
$ ls
bar1/  bar2/  bar2_1/  bar3/  foo1/  foo1_1/  foo1_3/  foo2/  foo3/  foo4/
```

after:

```
$ ls
bar1/  bar2/  bar3/  bar4/  foo1/  foo2/  foo3/  foo4/  foo5/  foo6/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex with mkdir:

`mkdir folder{1..100}`

Then verify your output!

```
ls -l 

folder1
folder2
folder3
..
folder100
```